# Automated Goal Seek - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, automation, goalseek

I have been using goal seek successfully to back into a known number. This works great with a handful of lines - now I need it for 100s (probably 1000s) of lines.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Col A = constant (known)

Col B = variable (unknown)

Col C = 1.5*Col B (unknown)

Col D = variable*2080 (unknown)

Col E = (Col C*Col A) (unknown)

Col F = Col D+Col E (Where I have been using the goal seek and manually entering Col G # into goal seek) - would like it to pull Col G's number

Col G = Known Number (i.e., what should be in Col F).

Can anyone help me automate?

Comment: You appear to have only a single variable. That means you can solve the equation (`F = G = (x * 2080) + (x * 1.5 * A)` for `x` (AKA `B`).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in Col B1

```
=G1/((A1*15)+2048)
```

Comment: 15 should be 1.5